# Where do the commas go with prepositional introductory phrases?

Tags: grammar, commas

"Over the river, through the woods, to Grandmother's house we go."

Where do the commas go with these introductory prepositional phrases?

1. Over the river, through the woods, to Grandmother's house, we go.
2. Over the river through the woods, to Grandmother's house we go.
3. Over the river, through the woods, to Grandmother's house we go.

Comment: Welcome! Can you share a bit more about why you're asking? Are you hoping to apply the principle to other sentences; if so, could you share more context? #2 has some interesting opportunities for ambiguity and confusion.

Comment: One reason to use a comma is to prevent misreading/misparsing. Without a comma, the reader could understand that the river ran through the woods. (BTW, I think the lyric is "Over the river *and* through the woods")

Comment: You can read the full text in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Over_the_River_and_Through_the_Wood). It has both a comma and the word "and".